# Web service not getting called using Async Task

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am required to connect to a web service and obtain an XML output using Android. The web service provides synonyms in English for a given word. The following Java code is provided by the API provider,

```
public class Thesaurus {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SendRequest("peace", "en_US", "test", "xml");
}
} // end of Thesaurus 

class SendRequest {
    final String endpoint = "http://thesaurus.altervista.org/thesaurus/v1";

    public SendRequest(String word, String language, String key, String output) {
     try {
        URL serverAddress = new URL(endpoint + "?word=" + URLEncoder.encode(word, "UTF-8") + "&language=" + language + "&key=" + key + "&output=" + output);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) serverAddress.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        int rc = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (rc == 200) {
            String line = null;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + '\n');
            }
            System.out.print(sb.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("HTTP error:" + rc);
        }
        connection.disconnect();

    } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (java.net.ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
} // end of SendRequest
```

However since you cannot do this in Android without using an Async task I have modified the code as follows,

```
class SendRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    final String endpoint = "http://thesaurus.altervista.org/thesaurus/v1";
    final String key = "test";
    final String language = "en_US";
    final String output = "xml";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL serverAddress = new URL(endpoint + "?word=" + URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8") + "&language=" + language + "&key=" + key + "&output=" + output);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) serverAddress.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            int rc = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (rc == 200) {
                String line = null;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + '\n');
                }
                synonymTxt = sb.toString();
            } else {
                synonymTxt = "HTTP error:" + rc;
            }
            connection.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        AlertDialog ad1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateAppointmentActivity.this).create();
        ad1.setTitle("Synonym Results");
        ad1.setMessage(synonymTxt);
        ad1.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        ad1.show();
    }
}
```

My problem here is that the post execution block gets executed but the output is given as empty. The Async task is used as an inner class and the variables "text" and "synonymtxt" are class level variables. I have been struggling with this for almost 12 hours now and my only suggestion is that the code does not wait till the Async task is completed. How can I get the output of this?

Comment: What do you get if you log the value if `synonymTxt ` after the line `synonymTxt = sb.toString();` ?

Comment: The AlertDialog in onPostExecute shows that it is empty.

Comment: Try printing it in the console log to see what is returned from the web service.

Comment: why don't you use rxJava?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was my own fault. I had put the permissions in the wrong place of the manifest. Relocated them and now it works